# Python 2 replacement specific column from CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some CSV files the format is ID, timestamp, customerID, email, etc. I want fill the Email column to empty and other columns keep it same. I'm using Python 2.7 and is restricted to use Pandas. Can anyone help me?
Thank you all for the help

My code below, but this is not that efficiency and reliable also if some raw have the strange character it will be broken the logic.

```
new_columns = [

    '\xef\xbb\xbfID', 'timestamp', 'CustomerID', 'Email', 'CountryCode', 'LifeCycle', 'Package', 'Paystatus', 'NoUsageEver', 'NoUsage', 'VeryLowUsage',
    'LowUsage', 'NormalUsage', 'HighUsage', 'VeryHighUsage', 'LastStartDate', 'NPS 0-8', 'NPS Score (Q2)', 'Gender(Q38)', 'DOB(Q39)',
    'Viaplay users(Q3)', 'Primary Content (Q42)', 'Primary platform(Q4)', 'Detractor (strong) (Q5)', 'Detractor open text(Q22)',
    'Contact Detractor (Q21)', 'Contact Detractor (Q20)', 'Contact Detractor (Q43)', 'Contact Detractor(Q26)', 'Contact Detractor(Q27)',
    'Contact Detractor(Q44)', 'Improvement areas(Q7)', 'Improvement areas (Q40)', 'D2 More value for money(Q45)', 'D2 Sport content(Q8)',
    'D2 Series content(Q9)', 'D2 Film content(Q10)', 'D2 Children content(Q11)', 'D2 Easy to start and use(Q12)',
    'D2 Technical and quality(Q13)',
    'D2 Platforms(Q14)', 'D2 Service and support(Q15)', 'D3 Sport content(Q16)', 'Missing Sport Content (Q41)',
    'D3 Series and films content(Q17)',
    'NPS 9-10', 'Recommendation drivers(Q28)', 'R2 Sport content(Q29)', 'R2 Series content(Q30)', 'R2 Film content(Q31)',
    'R2 Children content(Q32)', 'R2 Easy to start and use(Q33)', 'R2 Technical and quality(Q34)', 'R2 Platforms(Q35)',
    'R2 Service and support(Q36)',
    'Promoter open text(Q37)'

]

        with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
            print file_path
            reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
            first_row = next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                output_row = []
                for column_name in new_columns:
                    ind = first_row.index(column_name)
                    data = row[ind]
                    if ind == first_row.index('Email'):
                        data = ''
                    output_row.append(data)
                writer.writerow(output_row)
```

File format before
[image]

File format after
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are reordering the columns and clearing the email column:

```
    with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
        print file_path
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
        first_row = next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            output_row = []
            for column_name in new_columns:
                ind = first_row.index(column_name)
                data = row[ind]
                if ind == first_row.index('Email'):
                    data = ''
                output_row.append(data)
            writer.writerow(output_row)
```

I would suggest moving the searches `first_row.index(column_name)` and `first_row.index('Email')` out of the per row processing.

```
    with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
        print file_path
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
        first_row = next(reader)

        email = first_row.index('Email')       
        indexes = []
        for column_name in new_columns:
            ind = first_row.index(column_name)
            indexes.append(ind)

        for row in reader:
            output_row = []
            for ind in indexes:
                data = row[ind]
                if ind == email:
                    data = ''
                output_row.append(data)
            writer.writerow(output_row)
```

`email` is the index of the email column in the input. `indexes` is a list of the indexes of the columns in the input in the order specified by the `new_columns`.

Untested.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dict versions of the csv reader/writer to get the column by name. Something like this:

```
import csv
with open('./test.csv', 'r') as infile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=";")
   with open('./output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()
       for row in reader:
           row['Email'] = ''
           writer.writerow(row)
```